# ¿Vala tiene arrays asociativos?

Tags: array, diccionarios, vala

Estoy intentando de encontrar la forma de crear arrays asociativos, tales como los diccionarios en Python:

> diccionario = {"clave1": valor1, "clave2": valor2}

¿Cómo puedo implementarlo en Vala? o si no existe que otra solución sería más práctica.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GLib.HashTable`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.HashTable.html) es probablemente el más cercano:

```
var diccionario = new GLib.HastTable<string,string>();
diccionario["clave1"] = "valor1";
diccionario["clave2"] = "valor2";
```

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que precisaba ;)